# Why does this Cairo program put powers of 2 in the memory?

Tags: cairo-lang, starknet

I'm trying to solve [this bonus question](https://www.cairo-lang.org/docs/how_cairo_works/program_counter.html#program-counter-and-jumps) from the "How Cairo Works" tutorial. I ran the following function, opened the Cairo tracer and saw that the memory is full with powers of 2. Why is that?

```
func main():
    [fp + 1] = 2; ap++
    [fp] = 5201798304953761792; ap++
    jmp rel -1
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some leading questions that can help you reach the answer. Answers to the questions after a break:

1. Where does the `jmp rel -1` instruction jump to?
2. What does the target instruction do? What happens after it?
3. How did this instruction end up in the program section of the memory?

---

1. `jmp rel -1` is encoded in the memory at addresses 5-6. When it is executed, we have `pc = 5`, thus after the jump we will execute the instruction at `pc = 4`, which is `0x48307fff7fff8000`.
2. This bytecode encodes the instruction `[ap] = [ap - 1] + [ap - 1]; ap++` (to check, you can manually decode the flags and offsets [Edit: see below], or simply write a cairo program with this instruction and see what it compiles to). After it is executed, `pc` is increased by 1, so we again execute `jmp rel -1`, and so on in an infinite loop. It should be clear why this fills the memory with powers of 2 (the first 2, at address 10, was written by the `[fp + 1] = 2; ap++` instruction).
3. The instruction `[fp] = 5201798304953761792; ap++` has an immediate argument (the right hand side, 5201798304953761792). Instructions with immediate arguments are encoded as two field elements in the memory, the first encoding the general instruction (e.g. `[fp] = imm; ap++`), and the second being the immediate value itself. This immediate value is thus written in address 4, and indeed 5201798304953761792 is the same as `0x48307fff7fff8000`. Similarly, the `2` at address 2 is the immediate argument of the instruction `[fp + 1] = 2`, and the `-1` at address 6 is the immediate of `jmp rel -1`.

To summarize, this strange behavior is due to the relative jump moving to an address of an immediate value and parsing it as a standalone instruction. Normally this wouldn't occur, since `pc` is incremented by 2 after executing an instruction with an immediate value, and by 1 when executing an instruction without one, so it always continues to the next compiled instruction. The unlabeled jump was necessary here to reach this unexpected program counter.

---

How can one manually decode the flags and offsets of `0x48307fff7fff8000`? Consulting the [Cairo whitepaper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1063.pdf) (mostly pages 50-59), we see that the lower three 16-bit words encode offsets off<sub>dst</sub> = 0, off<sub>op0</sub> = off<sub>op1</sub> = -1 (the values `0x8000`, `0x7fff`, `0x7fff` are offset by 2<sup>15</sup>, or alternatively can be considered as signed integers, as detailed on page 51). The flag word is `0x4830`, which has 4 flags set to 1 and the rest are 0: the set flags, from least to most, are f<sub>4</sub>, f<sub>5</sub>, f<sub>11</sub> and f<sub>14</sub>, which correspond to the flags `OP1_AP`, `RES_ADD`, `AP_ADD1` and `OPCODE_ASSERT_EQ` (according to page 58).  Let us explore the meaning of these flags (derived from the constraints listed in pages 58-59):

- The `OP1_AP` flag means operand 1 is taken relative to `ap`, with offset off<sub>op1</sub>, i.e. `op1 = [ap - 1]`. Operand 0 and `dst` are also relative to `ap` by default (when the relevant flags are not set), and including the above offsets we see that `op0 = [ap - 1]`, `dst = [ap]`.
- The `RES_ADD` flag means the operation between `op0` and `op1` is addition, i.e. the constraint `res = [ap - 1] + [ap - 1]` is enforced.
- The `OPCODE_ASSERT_EQ` flag means this is as equality assertion command, which means `res` will be equaled to `dst` by enforcing `dst - res = 0`, which we now see is equivalent to `[ap] = [ap - 1] + [ap - 1]`.
- Finally, the `AP_ADD1` flag simply means `ap` is advanced by 1, which corresponds to the `ap++` part of the command.

Taken all together, we get the command `[ap] = [ap - 1] + [ap - 1]; ap++` as claimed.

Comment: could you add details about how to actually do the check "you can manually decode the flags and offsets, or simply write a cairo program with this instruction and see what it compiles to"? thx

Comment: so I was able to see the bytecode while compiling a simple program with the instruction, however I don't know how to decode the flags, could you help plz?

Comment: Hi @ClementWalter, I added a detailed explanation of how to decode the flags. Hope this helps! I should mention that this can be quite tricky, and while a fun puzzle, is certainly not a particularly important skill for a cairo programmer :) Perhaps it was misleading to give this as the first option, as this wasn't my first approach to solving the problem - I just guessed the command based on the output, and verified it by compiling, as you have.

Comment: Perhaps learning the cairo constraints (to the level of decoding instructions) can be helpful in understanding the limitations of a single equation assertion in cairo: as you can see from the flags and constraints in the whitepaper, there are not that many different possible operations and data sources. More complex assertions will often be compiled into multiple equation-assertion commands, with intermediary values, and understanding what is possible in a single command can help you minimize the number of steps needed for a computation, if you so desire.